# What exactly are ア行-category verbs?

Tags: verbs, dictionary, godan-verbs

The question [Why are there so many カ行、サ行、ラ行五段活用 verbs?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/80848/why-are-there-so-many-%e3%82%ab%e8%a1%8c-%e3%82%b5%e8%a1%8c-%e3%83%a9%e8%a1%8c%e4%ba%94%e6%ae%b5%e6%b4%bb%e7%94%a8-verbs) is about different verb categories. I was surprised to find a ア行-category mentioned, and when I checked on weblio, they seemed to have listed only four verbs in this category, at least for 五段 (https://www.weblio.jp/parts-of-speech/%E3%82%A2%E8%A1%8C%E4%BA%94%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8_1). To top it all of, they all end in 合う, which is by itself listed as ワ行, not ア行.

This all seems rather strange to me, so I would be grateful for an explanation.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: I was going to ask this question too, but I wanted a response to my first question first, haha - thanks for asking for me :)

Answer (score 1):

There are conjugation forms, and one of them is the five-stage conjugation.
There are pentadic conjugations, which are conjugated with each step of the syllabic chart "a-i-u-e-o" at the end of a word. (The most common verb conjugation is the five-step conjugation.
The five conjugations are the changes of the five conjugations: preemptive, continuous, terminating, linking, hypothetical, and imperative.

Take the example of 「合う」 in the link.

- The non sequential form (preceding the auxiliary verb "ない", "う", "れる", etc.)

  - 「合わ(wa)ない」 The sound of "a" ...... ア段
  - 「合お(o)う」 The sound of "o" ......... オ段
- Adjunctive form (preceding the auxiliary verbs "ます," "た," and "たい," etc.) Abortive forms (forms that are cut off by ","). The form preceding the auxiliary verb "て", "たり", "ながら", etc.)

  - 「合い(i)ます」 The sound of "i" ............ イ段
- Ending form (a form of saying off. The form preceding the auxiliary verb "まい" or "らしい". The form preceding the auxiliary verb "と," "から," "けれど," etc.)

  - 「合う(u)」 The sound of "u" ............ ウ段
- Adnominal form (preceding a noun or pronoun)

  - 「合う(u)とき」 The sound of "u" ............ u-dan
- Hypothetical form (preceding the particle "ば")

  - 「合え(e)ば」 The sound of "e" ......... エ段
- Imperative (the form of commanding and saying a sentence out loud)

  - 「合え(e)」 The sound of "e" ............ エ段

It goes like this.

- [未然形](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9C%AA%E7%84%B6%E5%BD%A2)
- [連用形](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%80%A3%E7%94%A8%E5%BD%A2)
- [終止形](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B5%82%E6%AD%A2%E5%BD%A2)
- [連体形](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%80%A3%E4%BD%93%E5%BD%A2)
- [仮定形](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%AE%E5%AE%9A%E5%BD%A2)
- [命令形](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%91%BD%E4%BB%A4%E5%BD%A2)

Comment: Are you sure you understand what Kaskade is asking about? It's hard to see how what you have written here answers the question. Also, it looks as if you've written "following" in a number of places where you intended to write "preceding."

Comment: I may not understand this question. I hope others will add a more correct answer.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. He is not asking what 五段 is, or what ワ行 is. He is specifically asking **what ア行 is.** If you look at the website he linked, you will see that there are a number of verbs under a category called “ア行五段活用”, listed *separately* from the category named “ワ行五段活用”. They all end in 合う, which itself is ワ行, not ア行. He wants to know what exactly “ア行五段活用” is.

Comment: I was wrong. Thank you for the explanation. @LittleWhole 

So what I should have explained is

1. in general, "ア行五段活用" is not used. 
2. it seems that some of the verbs contained in "ワア行五段活用" are listed as "ア行五段活用" in this site.

is it that?

Comment: By the way, even though your answer wasn't what Kaskade was looking for, it was very generous of you to take the time to write this detailed explanation! I should have mentioned that in my original comment. I'm very sorry I didn't, and I hope you will continue to share your knowledge here.